# How do I convert this data into a tabular format?

Tags: dataframe

This is the data: https://github.com/sealneaward/nba-movement-data/blob/master/data/01.01.2016.CHA.at.TOR.7z
I am not sure how to convert this data into a dataframe (likely multiple dataframes). Can anyone help me or direct me to a good resource?

Comment: You should be more specific (what kind of data) and keep it to code here (sample), not anywhere else.

Comment: there's a readme? https://github.com/sealneaward/nba-movement-data/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5 that code is in python though. How would I convert it to R? (sorry, I am very new to programming)

Comment: I wouldn't personally - it looks like you could use https://github.com/sealneaward/nba-movement-data/blob/master/movement/json_to_csv.py to convert the json (which is compressed in the .7z you linked) to csv and then you can load that in R and play as you wish.